# What does this mean on a stargazer table

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model, clustered-standard-errors

I am getting the following reported on my stargazer table after running a regression using felm:

> ```
> Standard errors may be too high due to more than 2 groups and exactDOF=FALSE
> ```

What is the significance of this and should I be worried about the purposes of my analysis? Indeed, I am getting very high t-stats and no significance on some coefficients.

Comment: Welcome. Please share your output to receive the best possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a quirk of the `stargazer` package but rather a warning message stemming from the summary output of a model estimated via the `felm()` function. Try `summary(your_model)` and the warning should remain.

The R Journal's treatise on the `lfe` [package](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-2/gaure.pdf) and the `felm()` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lfe/versions/2.8-5.1/topics/felm) in particular are always a good places to start. Here is an excerpt from Simen Gaure's paper (pp. 109-110):

> The standard errors for $\hat{\beta}$ are easily computed, and are identical to the the standard errors from `lm()` if we were to run it with all the dummies. However, there is a minor difference. The degrees of freedom depends on the rank of the matrix $D$, or $D^tD$, or the trace of $P$. The rank is easily computed for the cases with one or two factors, but requires a much more time consuming approach for 3 or more factors. The default approach of `felm()` is to assume that the column rank deficiency of $D$ is $e − 1$ when there are $e > 2$ factors. This may result in a too high value for the rank, hence a too low value for the degrees of freedom, which will yield too high standard errors. In most real cases the author has witnessed, the error is negligible. `felm()` has an argument `exactDOF` which may be set to `TRUE` to activate a more accurate computation of the rank.

In my reading of the paper, the warning is resulting from a rank-deficiency problem. If the deficiency is large relative to the degrees of freedom then it could affect your standard errors. You could ignore it (default behavior) or set `exactDOF = TRUE` which performs a rank computation procedure. This could become very demanding to compute with more than two factors. I have never had this problem myself, but I have found this warning message to be quite standard.

I cannot offer further guidance without seeing your model summary. You may be observing inflated uncertainty due to the "overestimation" of multiple factors, each of which contains an inordinate number of *levels*. Suppose you estimate a wage equation which is similar in style to examples presented in the documentation:

`log(wage) ~ x + factor(individual) + factor(firm)`

where the model contains two factors and some `x` covariate of interest. Individuals may change firms in a particular sector and so the data is not nested. Quoting from page 107 of Simen Gauvre's paper:

> In this case there are two factors, one for employees and one for firms. It may happen that one set of employees move between one set of firms, whereas another disjoint set of employees move between some other firms. There are no movements between these mobility groups, hence coefficients from different groups cannot be compared....It is shown...that for identification of the coefficients, it is sufficient to introduce a single reference level in each of the disjoint mobility groups, either a firm or an employee. `efactory()` chooses by default the level with the highest number of observations as a reference level, and sets the coefficient to 0. When interpreting the coefficients, they
> should never be compared between the components; a coefficient is only meaningful relative to the reference level in the component it belongs to.

Thus, the precise number of implicit dummies is easy to compute in settings involving two factors. But now suppose we introduce a third factor to spice things up:

`log(wage) ~ x + factor(individual) + factor(firm) + factor(title)`

where the model incorporates a factor denoting an individual's job title. `lfe`'s behavior in the presence of three factors is to "assume that the connected components of the two first factors are sufficient for identification, and a *single reference* (emphasis added) is used in each of the remaining factors" (see, p. 107). Estimability relies on a specific probabilistic test, and `getfe()` should issue a clear warning if it finds some identification problem. Concerns regarding "overestimation" in settings with more than two factors have been discussed in detail in other [forums](https://github.com/sgaure/lfe/blob/master/man/felm.Rd). In addition, the order of the factors in the model specification now becomes very important.

A super quick fix is to drop one of your factors, or simply move it. In fact, some have suggested removing one of the fixed effects (i.e., factors) and placing it onto the side of the model formula where you specify your $X$ variables. See [here](https://github.com/sgaure/lfe/issues/11) for a discussion of this.